# Facebook iOS SDK > 4.0 replacement for initWithAppId?

Tags: xcode, facebook, session, facebook-ios-sdk

I have two different FBAppId's, one for the eventual release and another for debugging purposes, and I was wondering since after SDK 4.0 it no longer has a concept of session states, how I might be able to "create session" with different appid's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Peter you should be using testApps of your main app for these purposes. Go to your dashboard and choose testApps and create one. It solves the same purpose and you don't have the session problem. 
Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps//test-apps/ and create a test app.

You can read more about this here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps . It reduces a lot of work for staging / QA test apps.